# Unity - I am watching a tutorial(Code Monkey) and he is using an event handler when I use the same thing it is throwing an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the error: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I tried to create an event handler so I could create an Interact button wth unity's new input system. I expected it to say "Interact!" as a placeholder in another script. It is throwing the error I mentioned above.

This is my code:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameInput : MonoBehaviour
{

    public event EventHandler OnInteractAction;

    private PlayerInputActions playerInputActions;

    private void Awake()
    {

        playerInputActions = new PlayerInputActions();

        playerInputActions.Player.Enable();

        playerInputActions.Player.Interact.performed += Interact_performed;
    }
    
    private void Interact_performed(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        if (OnInteractAction != null)
        {
            OnInteractAction(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public Vector2 GetMovementVectorNormalized()
    {

        Vector2 InputVector = playerInputActions.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        return InputVector;
    }

}
```

Comment: Most editors offer you the solution....

Comment: You should use Unitys event classes.  UnityEngine.Events namespace declares `UnityEvent` and `UnityAction` in place of the traditional c# events (though unity does use these under the hood).  The Unity versions are also serializable which allows hooking up events from the inspector.  You also do not need to create delegates because `UnityAction/Event` have generic versions that support up to 16 parameters.

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding and dont understand the jargon. This is 3rd C# script ever. I only understand a little cuz I was a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import it, by adding `using System;` to the top of your .cs file, like so:

```csharp
using System;

// your existing imports
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameInput : MonoBehaviour
{
  // ... your GameInput code goes here
}
```

Comment: I just didn't include it in the code above I do have the 3 using statements. Thank you though

Comment: @AkshithSribalaji Yes you have the 3 - but you don't have the 4th (`using System;`) that this answer specifies.